# CollectionProxy vs AssociationRelation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am wondering about the difference between `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` and `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation`.

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wheels
end

class Wheel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vehicle
end
```

**So if I do:**

`v = Vehicle.new`

`v.wheels # => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`

`v.wheels.all # => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>`

I have no idea what is the difference between them and why this is implemented this way?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html

Comment: I checked it before writing this post, but I didn't understand the difference between it and AssociationRelation. If you do please write it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Relation` are simple query objects before being turned into a query and executed, `CollectionProxy` on the other hand are a little bit more sophisticated.

First of all you get association extentions, you probably saw something that looks like this, assume a book store model that has many books

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books do
    def used
      where(is_used: true)
    end
  end
end
```

This way you get to call used books in a store using a syntax that looks like this

```
Store.first.books.used
```

But this is the most basic uses, you could use the attributes that are exposed to you in the collection proxy, which are `owner`, `reflection` and `target`

### Owner

The `owner` provides a a reference to the parent object holding the association

### Reflection

The `reflection` object is an instance of `ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssocciationReflection` and contains all the configuration options for the association.

### Target

The `target` is the association collection objects (or single object when `has_one` and `belongs_to`).

Using those methods you could do some conditons in your association extention, for example if we have a blog, we give access to all deleted posts to users who are admins (lame example I know)

```
Class Publisher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts do
    def deleted
      if owner.admin?
        Post.where(deleted: true)
      else
        where(deleted: true)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You also get access to two more methods which are `reset` and `reload`, the first one (`reset`) clears the cached association objects, the second one (`reload`) is more common and is used to `reset` and then loads the associated objects from the database.

I hope this explains how having a `CollectionProxy` class would be so useful

Answer (score 14):

Ok. The difference is pretty simple.

Explanation based on your example:

the association proxy in `v.wheels` has:

- the object in `v` as @owner;
- the collection of its wheels as @target;
- and the @reflection object represents a `:has_many` macro.

From [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html):

> Association proxies in Active Record are middlemen between the @owner
>   and the @target.
>   **The @target object is not loaded until needed.**

```
v = Vehicle.new
v.wheels # we are not sending any methods to @target object (collection of wheels)
# => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Which means, as soon as you call any method on the @target object (that holds collection of `wheels` in our case) the @target is loaded, and it becomes `ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation`.

```
v.wheels.all # sending the `all` method to @target (wheels)
# => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
```