# Rails: Model.association vs Model.association.all

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Pretty simple question that I haven't found an answer to surprisingly.

Pretend I have a user that has_many posts. What is the difference between:

`User.posts` and `User.posts.all`

They both seem to return the same thing, but seem to be different data types that are returned. `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` vs `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation` (for the .all). Does it matter which one I use if for example I want to show all posts on a users page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CollectionProxy vs AssociationRelation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683555/collectionproxy-vs-associationrelation)

Here is an explanation from a previous SO question that might help you out.