# Display ALL ads with specific category, returning nothing - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails (5.2.3) and trying to show all ads tagged with a specific category but i got an empty index

show.html.erb (category_view)

```
<% @category.ads.each do |ad| %>
<%= ad.category.try(:label) %>
<%= ad.title %>
<%= ad.user.first_name %>
<%= ad.publishing_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>
<%= ad.location %>
<%= ad.price %>
<%= ad.description %>
<% end %>
```

Category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ads
  belongs_to :categorytype
end
```

Ad.rb

```
class Ad < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
belongs_to :category
end
```

Categories_controller.rb

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

  def show

  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  @ads = @category.ads.published.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
end
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: Can you share the output for `@category.ads` for the selected category from rails console?

Comment: Category.find(1)
  Category Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Category id: 1, label: "Car", categorytype_id: 1>

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
@ads = @category.ads.published.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
```

with

```
@ads = @category.ads&.published&.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
```

and in the view

```
<% @ads.each do |ad| %>
  <%= ad.category.try(:label) %>
  <%= ad.title %>
   ....
<% end %>
```

Comment: i get this error

undefined local variable or method `ads' for #<#<Class:0x0000561b998e6e98>:0x00007fa3d9776710>
Did you mean?  @ads

and when i change it to @ads i get nothing it still empty

Comment: can you show the result of c = Category.find(1) and then after c.ads

Comment: irb(main):002:0> c = Category.find(1)
  Category Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Category id: 1, label: "Car", categorytype_id: 1>
irb(main):003:0> c.ads
  Ad Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "ads".* FROM "ads" WHERE "ads"."category_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["category_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Comment: So you are getting CollectionProxy rather than ActiveRecordRelation. You might find it useful in ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683555/collectionproxy-vs-associationrelation```